# MailChimp - Variable Content based on the FirstNames in the List

Tags: asp.net, api, html-email, mailchimp

I have a list named "Students" of 500 members. Email will be sent to each member. Two things in the email content will be specific to each member. First one is:

> Dear Michael

Michael will be replaced by each members First Name. Second is:

> Click here

Click here will have a link behind redirecting each member to different target.

Followed this [How to Create a campaign in MailChimp using ASP.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6385342/how-to-create-a-campaign-in-mailchimp-using-asp-net)

I am able to create a campaign using API, but I need to go further with or without API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done this before for an email using personalisation. I didn't send it through MailChimp but I found this article that could help you: http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/getting-started-with-merge-tags/

In your list if you add a field for the student's first name and another field for the the link then you should be able to use merge tags to add that data to wherever you want it to be in your email.

Comment: Worked. That was what I am after.